# Adobe AIR iOS export says "Map failed"

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

When trying to export Adobe AIR Flex app for Apple iOS - sometimes the compiler say "**Map Failed**".
It happens with different compilers, SDK's and different projects.
It only happens when exporting for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This steps solved the problem for me:

1. Exit FlashBuilder and make sure its process is terminated
2. Close some desktop apps and make sure you have enough FREE RAM
3. Open FlashBuilder again
4. Clear the project (rebuild)
5. Export the project again
6. *Optional* If it still not works after few attempts - try with different compiler/SDK

**UPDATE**
Major reason for the error seems to be many build assets included in packaging. Make sure you exclude the not needed assets (psd files, video, etc..)